# NoClassDefFoundError Exception for android 2.2 using fragments with frame layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, noclassdeffounderror, android-framelayout

Thanks In Advance.

I am using sherlockActionbar and in the main activity layout i am using FrameLayout as Follows

The Mainactivity layout file will look like this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    />
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" style="@android:style/ButtonBar" 
android:background="#111">

<Button android:id="@+id/menu" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Menu"
    android:background="#111"/>
 <Button android:id="@+id/offers" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Offers" 
  android:background="#111" />
  <Button android:id="@+id/home" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Home"
    android:background="#111"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/cart" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Cart" 
    android:background="#111"/>
```

and in the main activity i  am just replacing the fragment as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {
  SlidingMenu menu ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu, null);
    String[] items = new String[]{"Menu","Offers","Cart","Todays Special"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, items);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);



    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setMenu(view);
   menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);

    menu.setBehindOffset(120);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);
   AreaSelection AreaFragment=new AreaSelection();

    final android.app.FragmentTransaction ft =   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,AreaFragment ,"Area"); 
    ft.commit();


}
```

Since all the code works well for android device having version greater then 3.0 but its not working in below versions getting the error of Class Deff Not Found

The Area Selection Fragment will look like this

```
public class AreaSelection extends Fragment{


MainDatabase db;

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater paramLayoutInflater, ViewGroup paramViewGroup, Bundle paramBundle)
      {

        View localView = paramLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.area_select, paramViewGroup, false);
        db=new MainDatabase(getActivity());
        Button proceed=(Button)localView.findViewById(R.id.proceed);

        proceed.setOnClickListener(this.ProccedListener);
        String[] area = new String[]{"Sangvi","Aundh","University","Shivaji Nagar","E-Square Area"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinner_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity() ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, area);

        Spinner s=(Spinner)localView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        s.setAdapter(spinner_adapter);

        return localView;


      }
  }
```

The Logcat Is As Follows

```
10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    com.community.ashwamedh.AreaSelection
10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.community.ashwamedh.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 10-06 11:39:00.988: E/AndroidRuntime(280):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please Help Me

thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

The Fragement class is first introduced in Homecomb(Android 3.0). If you want to use this feature in older versions of Android you should import it from the support library. Make sure you’re using the `android.support.v4.app` imports and not their equivalents from `android.app`.